# How to show google analytics of my website in my backend

Tags: javascript, json, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to show my google analytics on my admin panel. I have followed the [google analytics api](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) . I created service side authorization and downloaded the json data

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "xxxx",
    "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
     "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
     "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
     "client_x509_cert_url":"xxxxxx"
}
```

After creating above json and copied js code mentioned in that tutorial.

In the js code its asked for the

```
   gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
      }
   });
```

Here the problem is i can't find the ACCESS_TOKEN.  I just replaced with private key, client id, private key id and tried but it shows 401 error.

May be its silly problem. but i don't know how to get this. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `getAuthResponse`? This method returns the access token which you need to use.

> getAuthResponse()
>
> Returns:  Object
>
> Gets authentication data returned by the original authorization
>   request. The returned object includes the access token, which can be
>   usually to manually make authenticated requests.

See here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for answer. when i use this gapi.analytics.auth.getAuthResponse()  it shows undefined. In the google developer document the function doesn't includes any parameter then how it find my api?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly you skipped [step 3 from the linked documentation](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/).

### Step 3: Use the JSON key data to request an access token

The access token is obtained from running the python code:

```
# service-account.py

import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'path/to/json-key.json'

# Load the key file's private data.
with open(KEY_FILEPATH) as key_file:
  _key_data = json.load(key_file)

# Construct a credentials objects from the key data and OAuth2 scope.
_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    _key_data['client_email'], _key_data['private_key'], SCOPE)

# Defines a method to get an access token from the credentials object.
# The access token is automatically refreshed if it has expired.
def get_access_token():
  return _credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

The example you have linked to is [opensource](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools) and this method is called on the server side and the access token is returned through a web application template variable.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your answer. i have written this code in php. How can i use python in that?

Comment: Here is the auth code for php: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php basically you need to have a server side operation which uses a service account to generate the access_token and then somehow allow the client code access to that token. Django makes using template variables easy. If you can run the php process server side and get the access token to the client it should work similarly.